# Running a Docker container on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Where is my web app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

- I deployed an Application from a Docker Container to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Using the Elastic Beanstalk Console.
- After finishing deploying Web Application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Environment status is green.
- I clicked the URL link on the environment dashboard to view
  my web application.

**It always navigates to web page have string**

```
Congratulations!
Your Docker Container is now running in Elastic Beanstalk on your own dedicated environment in the AWS Cloud
```

I read log file, I don't see any error.
Here's its link: http://dockstalker-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/
Where is my web app? Do i miss anything?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y git git-core wget zip nodejs npm

EXPOSE 8080

# startup
ADD start.sh /tmp/  
RUN chmod +x /tmp/start.sh  
CMD ./tmp/start.sh
```

**start.sh**

```
cd /tmp

rm -rf docker-node-test; true

git clone https://github.com/incrediblemolk/docker-node-test.git

cd docker-node-test

npm install

nodejs app.js
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
        "Name": "ubuntu:14.04"
    },
    "Ports": [
        { 
            "ContainerPort": "8080"
        }
    ]
}
```

Before I hit the beanstalk I put 3 files into a .zip file. Call it aws-test.zip

Head to the AWS developer console and select "Elastic Beanstalk". Then pick "Create New Application".

1. Pick an application name.
2. Environment tier: Web Server
3. Predefined Configuration: Docker
4. Environment type: Load balancing, autoscaling
5. On the next screen select Upload your own and find the zip you created.
6. Additional Resources. Next.
7. Configuration Details. Next.
8. Environtment Tags. Next.
9. Scroll down and click Launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Congratulations! ..." page is what you usually see when you choose "Sample application" option in the Application Version step:

[image]

Please double-check what version you have specified. Also, it might be useful to check this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deployment.source.html

Comment: Hey, was it the root cause? If yes, could you please accept my answer? Thanks :)